# Customization of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on camera application in which I want to set the screen of the camera i.e camera window appear for particular frame. And in front of camera screen the cut out image is coming so that user can see the background through the cut out part of the image and capture the image. So any one know to do this i.e. customization of UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` has a property named `cameraOverlayView`. Use this to set your camera overlay as any view you like. Use normal view transparency for letting the user see parts of the live camera view.